# NHibernate Profiler does not show query plan

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, mysql.data, nhibernate-profiler

My application uses NHibernate to connect to a MySQL database. The profiling works fine, but the links at the bottom ("See the x row(s) resulting from this statement" and "Query plan for this statement") do not work. When I click on the query plan statement, nothing happens. When I click on the "See x rows" link, a new window is opened that does not display anything. When I click on "Edit Connection" and select the correct MySQL connection string, I get the following error: "could not find connection type mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlconnection" What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that NHibernate Profiler does not know the path to `MySql.Data.dll` and therefore cannot show the results or the query plan. The solution is very simple. In the Edit Connection window, you have to select the `MySql.Data.dll` file by clicking on **Browse**. After selecting it, click on **OK** and everything works fine.